# Reindexing python data frame is creating NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this, with monthly data points:

```
   Date        Value
1  2010-01-01  18.45
2  2010-02-01  18.13
3  2010-03-01  18.25
4  2010-04-01  17.92
5  2010-05-01  18.85
```

I want to make it daily data and fill in the resulting new dates with the current month value. For example:

```
   Date        Value
1  2010-01-01  18.45
2  2010-01-02  18.45
3  2010-01-03  18.45
4  2010-01-04  18.45
5  2010-01-05  18.45 
....
```

This is the code I'm using to add the interim dates and fill the values:

```
today = get_datetime('US/Eastern') #.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
enddate='1881-01-01'
idx = pd.date_range(enddate, today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), freq='D')
df = df.reindex(idx)
df = df.fillna(method = 'ffill')
```

The output is as follows:

```
                     Date   Value
2010-01-01 00:00:00  NaN    NaN
2010-01-02 00:00:00  NaN    NaN
2010-01-03 00:00:00  NaN    NaN
2010-01-04 00:00:00  NaN    NaN
2010-01-05 00:00:00  NaN    NaN
```

The logs show that the `NaN` values appear just before the `.fillna` method is invoked. So the forward fill is not the culprit.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

***option 3***
safest approach, very general
up-sample to daily, then group monthly with a transform

The reason why this is important is that your day may not fall on the first of the month.  If you want to ensure that that days value gets broadcast for every other day in the month, do this

```
df.set_index('Date').asfreq('D') \
    .groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M')).Value \
    .transform('first').reset_index()
```

***option 2***
`asfreq`

```
df.set_index('Date').asfreq('D').ffill().reset_index()
```

***option 3***
`resample`

```
df.set_index('Date').resample('D').first().ffill().reset_index()
```

For `pandas=0.16.1`

```
df.set_index('Date').resample('D').ffill().reset_index()
```

---

All produce the same result over this sample data set

[image]

Comment: Thx. I tried Option 3 and got an error. I'm wondering if the methods are not recognized in the environment I'm working in (Quantopian). Do you have to import anything specific for these to operate?

Comment: I'm running pandas version 0.16.1

Comment: TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Comment: No error this time. But it did not make it daily data. Odd.

Comment: I can see it in the logs and it creates errors downstream.

Comment: It's always the first of the month:

Comment: https://www.quandl.com/data/MULTPL/SHILLER_PE_RATIO_MONTH-Shiller-PE-Ratio-by-Month

Comment: I just installed a virtual environment with pandas 0.16.1 and options 1 and 2 seem to work fine.  I edited the post for option 3.

Comment: Same result with all of them. I can't say you haven't tried. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @jhomme Sorry we couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add index to the original dataframe before calling reindex

```
test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4), index=pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-01-04'), columns=['test'])
test.reindex(pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-01-05'), method='ffill')
```